# Session shutdown function, nothing seems to work

Tags: php, session

I've spend several days, 
I've searched a lot, here and via Bing
I've fully explored OFFICIAL PHP page
at:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

-- All comments, all functions.

But NOTHING HELPED. ABSOLUTE.

There's only one thing I need:

Invoke some function after SESSION is closed (for example, user has closed his browser).

Here is the point: AGAIN --- Invoke some function after user closed agent --- i.e session ID doesn't valid anymore

So, I've tried, to use old-style approach i.e override default session handler:

via,

```
session_set_save_handler("sess_open", "sess_close", "sess_read", "sess_write", "sess_destroy", "sess_gc");
```

that something looks like this:

```
function sess_close() {
    print "Session closed.\n";
    return true;
}

function sess_read($sess_id) {
    print "Session read.\n";
    print "Sess_ID: $sess_id\n";
    return '';
}

function sess_write($sess_id, $data) {
    print "Session value written.\n";
    print "Sess_ID: $sess_id\n";
    print "Data: $data\n\n";
    return true;
}

function sess_destroy($sess_id) {
    print "Session destroy called.\n";
    return true;
}

function sess_gc($sess_maxlifetime) {
    print "Session garbage collection called.\n";
    print "Sess_maxlifetime: $sess_maxlifetime\n";
    return true;
}
```

But this also doesn't work when a user closes browser.
Why this doesnt work?

Comment: because when browser is closed it does not inform server... and php file is not executed... You should check if session is valid, not if it is invalid.

Comment: you cannot do that .. instead you have to run a "cleanup daemon/cronjob" which does this.

Comment: @Sampo I used to think the way you do. But I saw in some social networks, they invoke some function after browser is closed. it's exactly php, not js, telling that session doesn't exists anymore. For example, some user closed browser , then after 1 seconds another users can see him as offline. Its not ping-style (in some time) approach.

Comment: @metal_fan It is ping style for backup + AJAX is used to achieve this realtime (or almost). Database stores online information and AJAX requests are used to keep it up to date. There's no need to invoke any function at browser close, timeout for users is all you need. Check for database values with all requests, if time runs out and last seen timestamp not updated then user has closed browser, network failed, cpu died, wife coming back to house or something just prevents user to "ping" server.

Comment: some sites use user activity to generate AJAX request and update user presence in website, cron jobs can later check Sessions ID and start cleaning up, never tried though why not set session maxlifetime a low value ?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix setting max-lifetime is great if it's fairly simple system where it's being used. The primary drawback of this approach is that user could still use the system, but session may expire. that's the problem

Comment: @Sampo Ok, let's Assume that this is ping-style via AJAX. So how does the system exactly know that user has closed the browser in less than one second? One thing that may be used is "less than one sec" AJAX ping to the server-side application. But it's very very expensive for whole system. So this scenario isn't good for online/offline users. Yes AJAX pings to the server is very popular solution and commonly used for this purpose, but I wonder how some social networks (except facebook cause they use AJAX pings), do know if user session no longer exists in milliseconds

Comment: @metal_fan: You may wish so hard, so much, with so much tears - but: you won't gonna get what you are looking for. before using a tool, keep a moment and consider if it's the right tool for the job. Sessions for example are not the right tool for the job to find out if the user closed the browser. Search the site for: *"How to determine if the user closed the browser?"* and you will learn more.

Comment: @hakre thanks for useful suggestion anyway. I've searched for this before, even in javascript tools (also forums, discussions), in stackoverflow too. But the questions like "how to determine if user closed the browser" guides me back to AJAX and sessions

Comment: Yeah, then implement it. But not the way you did. You are just too far of. Just read more, not less. And instead of getting frustrated look for some other way of solution. Keep it simple.

Comment: Just a quick point, using CAPS the way you do is not needed it makes you look DESPERATE or DUMB. I'm sure you are NEITHER.

Comment: @hakre I'm beating my head against the wall for several weeks... There're only limited number of solutions of "how to determine if user closed the browser". First solution: javascript window.onunload method. This works almost fine if user closed the tab in browser not browser itself. The main drawback is that user can continue using the system by opening new tab in browser and here will be paradox user session ID still exists and there was ajax request to mark somewhere that user offline.

Comment: Second solution: Compare session ID against database row that was updated on user log on. But there's a problem -- it would make thousands and thousands useless rows which of course would make perfomance of queries down

Comment: @metal_fan: Reduce your frustration: There is no real solution at all to determine that. So relax, just work from the premise that it never works. Then, re-think what you're trying to do. If it *needs* that functionality, you need to code a browser add-on first. Okay? **BROWSER-ADDON** - was that drastic enough?

Comment: @hakre Browser addon, sounds good :) But I personally beelive that everybody hates to install third-party addons, so if they wouldn't install that addon then the system won't work correctly... Well, thank for your suggestion, I should try thinking about this in many different ways or should make custom php build with some improves  inside sessions, so i'll try them both